# angularjs $compile bugs the onload event on an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

i am trying to create a print provider that receives a template and a scope and compiles it into html than injects an iframe with this html content in the body tag and calls print on the `onload` event on the iframe to print this content.
Code looks like this:

```
myApp.provider('$print', function() {
    return {
        $get: function($document, $interpolate, $compile, $timeout) {
            var $print = {};

            function printFrame(content) {
              var frameContent = '<!doctype html>' +
                  '<html>' +
                    '<body onload="window.print()">' +
                      content +
                    '</body>' +
                  '</html>';

              // inject iframe into DOM
              var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
              iframe.id = 'print-frame';
              iframe.style.display = 'none';

              var body = $document.find('body').eq(0);
              body.append(iframe);
              iframe = document.getElementById('print-frame');

              // fill iframe with print content
              var iframeContent = (iframe.contentWindow) ? iframe.contentWindow : (iframe.contentDocument.document) ? iframe.contentDocument.document : iframe.contentDocument;
              iframeContent.document.open();
              iframeContent.document.write(frameContent);
              iframeContent.document.close();
            };

            $print.iframe1 = function(printOptions) {
                var printScope = printOptions.scope.$new();
                var htmlToPrint = $interpolate(printOptions.template)(printScope);
                printFrame(htmlToPrint);
            }

            $print.iframe2 = function(printOptions) {
                var printScope = printOptions.scope.$new();
                $timeout(function() {
                    var htmlToPrint = $compile(printOptions.template)(printScope);
                    printScope.$digest();
                    printFrame(htmlToPrint.html());
                });
            }

            return $print;
        }
    }
});
```

The issue i'm having is when i use `$interpolate` for example, the provider works fine, the iframe `onload` event waits until the images and everything is loaded before it calls the print, but when i use `$compile`, for some reason the iframe's `onload` event fires before images are loaded.

I created a JSFiddle for this example, if you disable the cache you can see how on interpolate, the print is called only after that big image is loaded, but on compile, the print message opens right away.

Hope someone can help me with this, thanks in advance, Daniel!

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16737/

Answer (score 2):

`htmlToPrint` does have two element `h1` & the other one is `img` tag, but the Problem is when you are doing `htmlToPrint.html()` from the `iframe2` function it does only returns `SuperHero`, It doesn't return the other part of the html.

For solving this issue you could use you need to wrap your template with some div, so that while doing `.html()` on element will return correct elements.

**Template**

```
template: '<div>'+
            '<h1>{{printTitle}}</h1>'+
            '<img style="width: 1000px" src="http://velocityagency.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/go.jpg"'>+'
          '<div>',
```

Additionally you need to set some small amount of timeout in miliseconds like `10` inside the `$timeout` function.

```
$timeout(function() {
    printFrame(htmlToPrint.html());
},10);
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t6u1vLkd/1/)

**Update**

Above solution didn't work for if I disabled the browser cache, I think we are sending a page to printing before rendering the image on the page.

```
$print.iframe2 = function(printOptions, scope) {
    var printScope = printOptions.scope.$new();
    var htmlToPrint = $compile(printOptions.template)(printScope);

    angular.element(htmlToPrint.find('img').on('load', function() {
        $timeout(function() {

            console.log("Img loaded")
            printFrame(htmlToPrint.html());
        });
    }))

}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t6u1vLkd/3/)

Comment: you're right, i updated my JSFiddle but this does not fix the problem that i'm having, the $compile print still opens the brwoser print modal before the image is loaded and so the print does not have the image inside

Comment: @PacuraruDaniel look at my edit..will fix your problem..Thanks :)

Comment: @PankajParkar I think a timeout of 0 should be OK (so that the $digest finishes).

Comment: @PankajParkar hey man, i tried the fiddle but it does the same thing to me, when i open the compile print, there is no image the first time, you can see that if you disable cache and open it after refresh page

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe nope..I tried that already.I'm amazed that won't work..thats why I include a timeout value..

Comment: @PacuraruDaniel yes..Its not working by disabling cache..I think we need to wait for print until image gets loaded to the DOM..

Comment: i feel like the problem is somewhere else, i mean i put static html after i call $compile and it still does not work, i feel like the $compile function somehow messes the onload event on the iframe http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16739/

Comment: @PacuraruDaniel do look at my new update..seems like the image loading issue..I updated the answer with working fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87830/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-pacuraru-daniel).

Comment: @PacuraruDaniel its work on my end..please check updated fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue on this, the problem is that when i'm compiling the html, the images start to download and get cached by the browser, and when i inject them inside the iframe, the onload event on the iframe thinks they are already downloaded and does not wait for them.